# How to add corrupted submit button?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to have form for possible answers in poll and two submit buttons. First one passing all text fields, second one passing one of these fields as nil causing validation error. This is my _form.html.haml file:

```
= form_for [@poll, @question] do |f|
  - if @question.errors.any?
    #error_explanation
      %h2= "#{pluralize(@question.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this question from being saved:"
      %ul
        - @question.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
          %li= msg

  .field
    = f.label :title
    = f.text_field :title
  %p
    = f.label :kind
  .radio
    -@kind_options.each do |option|
      %label
        =f.radio_button :kind, option[1]
        =option[0]
  =f.fields_for :possible_answers do |c|
    %p
      =c.text_field :title, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Enter a possible answer"
  .actions
    = f.submit 'Save', class: "btn btn-primary"

  - x = f
  = x.hidden_field :kind, :value => nil
  = x.submit 'Corrupted Sumbit Button', class: "btn btn-primary"
```

It seems that there is no difference if I submit x or f, :kind is blank even I choose it in radio button and click on f.submit button. How to work this out?

Comment: Why are you using `x` as an alias? Why do you have two fields called `kind`?

Comment: I have two fields called `kind` because I want to choose which value i want to submit: option[1]/option[0] or nil. Submit f -> kind is value, submit x -> kind is nil.

Comment: You can't have two fields with the same name or you'll get conflicting values.

Comment: So how I could submit those fields omitting (or not) :kind, depending on which button i have chosen?

Comment: You submit two different fields, then use the button parameter to determine which one to use. You should see the button itself passed in as a parameter, but only the one that was clicked.

Comment: Not sure why no one has ask **Why** you would want to do this in the first place?